# Count repeating events in pandas timeseries

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

*I'm working on very basic pandas since a few days but struggle with my current task:*

I have a (non normalized) timeseries with items that contains a userid per timestamp. So something like: (date, userid, payload) So think about an server logffile where I would like to find how much IPs return within a certain timeperiod.

Now I like to find how much of the users have **multiple items within an intervall** for example in 4 weeks etc. So it's more a sliding window than constant intervals on the t-axis.

So my approaches were:

- df_users reindex on userids
- or multiindex?

Sadly I didn't found a way to generate the results successfully.
So all in all I'm not sure how I realize that kind of search with Pandas, or maybe this is easier to implement in pure Python? Or do I just lack some keywords for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some dummy data that I think fits your problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],  
                   'time': ['2013-1-1', '2013-1-2', '2013-1-3', 
                        '2013-1-1', '2013-1-5', '2013-1-7', 
                        '2013-1-1', '2013-1-7', '2013-1-12']})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

This approach requires some kind non-missing numeric column to count with, so just add a dummy one.

```
df['dummy_numeric'] = 1
```

My approach to the problem is this.  First, `groupby` the id and iterate so we are working with one user id worth of data at time.  Next, `resample` the irregular data up to daily values so it is normalized.

Then, using the `rolling_count` function, count the number of observations in each X day window (using 3 here).  This works because the upsampled data will be filled with NaN and not counted.  Notice that only the numeric column is being passed to `rolling_count`, and also note the use of double-brackets (which results in a DataFrame being selected rather than a series).

```
window_days = 3
ids = []
for _, df_gb in df.groupby('id'):
    df_gb = df_gb.set_index('time').resample('D')
    df_gb = pd.rolling_count(df_gb[['dummy_numeric']], window_days).reset_index()
    ids.append(df_gb)
```

Combine all the data back together, mark the spans with more than observations

```
df_stack = pd.concat(ids, ignore_index=True)
df_stack['multiple_requests'] = (df_stack['dummy_numeric'] > 1).astype(int)
```

Then groupby and sum, and you should have the right answer.

```
df_stack.groupby('time')['multiple_requests'].sum()
Out[356]: 
time
2013-01-01    0
2013-01-02    1
2013-01-03    1
2013-01-04    0
2013-01-05    0
2013-01-06    0
2013-01-07    1
2013-01-08    0
2013-01-09    0
2013-01-10    0
2013-01-11    0
2013-01-12    0
Name: multiple, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the snipped Chris :) Your example works fine, but need numeric IDs/index. So how can I create unique numeric IDs from strings. e.g. IPs? I tried different approaches, but I guess I'm still a newbie :/

Comment: @MaM - See the edit.  ID doesn't need to be numeric, you just need some numeric column in the DataFrame to count.

Comment: Thank you once more :) The patch is ok, but it fails when let's say "{'id': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'],..." Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: @MaM - Sorry, see one last edit.  I didn't realize that `rolling_count` coerces to numeric which is why my test cased works but yours didn't.  This edit should work in the general case.